# error 403 intermitently in my web page

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have an mvc application in c#, hosted on azure. When I load the page the first time I get 403 errors for images and sometimes js content.

But when I reload the page maybe 3 times, the page works perfectly and the errors disappear. Can anyone help me?

I've got my styles and js in bundles like this:

```
BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/paquete/jquery").Include(
                "~/content/js/jquery/jquery-laversionxxx.js",
                "~/content/js/jquery/jquery-laversionxxx.min.js"
                ));
```

and some images that throw 403 errors are referenced from the style page, like:

```
.header .clave, .header .clave:focus {
    border: solid 1px #55779f;
    border-radius: 3px;
    height: 32px;
    background: url(/content/img/pass.jpg) no-repeat left top;
    padding-left: 40px;
    color: #55779f;
}
```

Comment: Not sure which directory your CSS is in but don't you want it to be: background: url('/content/img/pass.jpg') no-repeat left top?  You want quotes around your image URL

Comment: Check from the Developer Tools in the browser, if certain resources require permission which is only granted after a successfull login ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This sounds more like a permissions issue and not a coding issue. Please check your files and ensure they have proper permissions.

Comment: its when i change the charge order of the file, it simplily get crazy, in the local application works find, but the test app, steel not working find sometimes, i dont know what else could it be.